# Can the Enderdragon be killed by Snow Golems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i was reading the wiki and learned that Snow Golems can do 1 damage to the Ender Dragon however under the trivia sections of the Ender Dragon it says that it can't be harmed by any other mob

so i am wondering, can a Snow Golem kill an Ender Dragon (given i destroy Ender Crystals and prevent it healing)

Comment: You could probably kill an Enderdragon with snow golems but it would take a while.

Comment: It is practically impossible because of Enderdragon being healed by crystals. But theoretically, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, here's the scoop. After I found this question, I was actually really curious if it would work, so I went and tried it out. The Snow Golems deal little to no damage to the Ender Dragon. So I guess it could be possible, BUT the Snow Golems attack ANY hostile mob, so even while you want the to try to kill the Ender Dragon, they will attack the Endermen as well. So it might be possible, but it would take a very long time for it to actually happen. Another downside is that whenever the Ender Dragon sweeps in, the Snow Golems are pushed out of the way, so most of the time they fall off, or are killed, and never get a chance to land a shot on the Ender Dragon.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nearly impossible due to Enderdragon's healing crystals, If you are willing to do this in survival try to take out the crystal FIRST! then summon a gigantic group of Snowgolems and try not to create them near the edge or simply make a wall of obsidian so the EnderDragon wouldn't break it!

Answer (score -2):

No, they can't. I've tried it before, the ender dragon doesn't take damage from mobs apart from ghasts and withers because of their explosions. With mods they can hurt him.

Answer (score -3):

Technically, yes. However the amount of snowgolems you would need would be enormous. You would have to constantly make new ones because the ender dragon would kill them.

Comment: This does not address the core of the issue at all, nor does it add anything to the above answer.

Comment: @Gigazelle except the fact that the amount of golems needed would be incredibly high.